# Use class.getResource() to load file within .jar?

Tags: java, maven

I have the following directory structure in my java project:

[image]

This project is managed by `Maven`, and when package all resources are put into a single `.jar` file.
Within `Utils.java` I'm loading `car.jpg`, and since the texture file is on the classpath I'm using the following method to get a handle on the file:

```
URL url = Utils.class.getResource("/textures/car.jpg");
```

I've seen a lot of confusion about which method to use when getting a reference to a file on the classpath.
Is `class.getResource()` the right method to use? Or does `class.getResourceAsStream()` offer any benefits?

Comment: Well if you just want an `InputStream`, I'd use `getResourceAsStream`. If you're working with something which is happy to use a `URL`, then us `getResource`. Is your code not working, or are you really just asking which of those two methods to use?

Comment: I don't see any differences. It just depends on which return value you can use. For example `ImageIcon` take an `URL` but not an `InputStream` as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are pretty much the same except for the return object. `getResourceAsStream` eventually calls `getResource` and returns an opened `InputStream` from the `URL` object as shown in the following snippet from the `ClassLoader` class:

```
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    URL url = getResource(name);
    try {
        return url != null ? url.openStream() : null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: While its generally a good idea to look at the source; you missed that ClassLoader is an abstract class and the method isn't final. Implementations may overwrite it (e.g. URLClassLoader) for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Given that the javadocs say ***exactly the same thing*** for both methods, I'd assume there are no benefits

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from getResource() whenever possible. Prefer getResourceAsStream() where you can.

The main reasoning behind this rule is that new URL(URL.toString()) for resources often breaks in totally unexpected ways depending on the class loader which provided the original URL.

Unlike what it look like on first glance, two URL's of equal string representation *are not treated the same*, depending on how they were constructed. That isn't a problem for URL's of standardized protocols. But it is for URL's generated by a ClassLoader; a ClassLoader can provide you an URL constructed this way:

```
 new URL(URL context, String spec, URLStreamHandler handler)
```

where the ClassLoader specifies its own URLStreamHandler. The handler information is lost when such an URL is ever converted to String, and it can't be recovered. You then have a seemingly valid URL that inexplicably doesn't work. Spare yourself the trouble :)